# Fluctuate Website banner When Scroll up and When Scroll down a white space appear in down side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Hii Guys Actually I am Designing a mobile friendly Website. After Testing I get a Problem And the **Problem is In mobile Side** When I do Scroll Website In Computer it Scrolls Well But **when I do scroll down in Mobile a small White space appears For fraction of seconds on down** part and **it's banner Fluctuate(Going down and then normal) or we can say zoom in**  And when **Scroll up** it's **banner Fluctuate(Going Up and then normal) or we can say zoom out.**

Comment: Can we see the relevant code, please?

Comment: I don't Know What code Gives that problem Its a Whole site style sheet If you want then we can connect on teamviewer and you can see this stylesheet

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend new users review [ask] for tips on forming their questions. Unfortunately, there is not enough information here to provide you any meaningful guidance. Can you please include a [mcve] and an explanation of the desired/expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ?  Without that, it is unlikely anyone will be able to give you much helpful direction.